# I can't map more than 18 fields in form with model

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

In my `Play Scala Project` I have more than `18` fields in my form.I inserted a form values from input `type` `submit` to `DB` If fields were less than 18.If I add more than `18` fields in `form mapping` it shows error like below

```
missing arguments for method unapply in object EmployeeRegister; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

**controllers/Employees.scala**

```
val employeeForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "employeeid" -> ignored(None: Option[Int]),
      "employeename" -> nonEmptyText,
      "employeedesc" -> nonEmptyText,     
    .....
    .....      
      "languages" -> list(number)   
      )(models.EmployeeRegister.apply)(models.EmployeeRegister.unapply))
```

**models/Employee.scala**

```
case class EmployeeRegister(
  employeeid: Option[Int] = None,
  employeename: String,
  employeedesc: String,
  .....
  ......
  languages: List[Int]

  )
```

**What I tried**

I used `nested values` concept for adding more than `18` fields.It didn't show any error but `form submission` didn't work It forwarded to same page by 
 using this `error handling` code.

```
employeeForm.bindFromRequest.fold(             

            formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.employeeRegisterForm(formWithErrors),
               employee => {
               ....
               ...
               }
```

**nested values**

**controller/Employees.scala**

```
 val employeeForm = Form(
        mapping(
          "employeeid" -> ignored(None: Option[Int]),
          "employeename" -> nonEmptyText,
          "employeedesc" -> nonEmptyText,     
        .....
        ..... 
       "os" -> mapping(
          "operatingsystem" -> text,   
            "osversion" -> text, 
            "osbit" -> text      
        )(models.OS.apply)(models.OS.unapply),
          "languages" -> list(number)   
          )(models.EmployeeRegister.apply)(models.EmployeeRegister.unapply))
```

**models/employee.scala**

```
 case class EmployeeRegister(
      employeeid: Option[Int] = None,
      employeename: String,
      employeedesc: String,
      .....
      ......
      os:OS,
      languages: List[Int]

      )

      case class OS(
       operatingsystem: String,   
      osversion: String,
      osbit:String  
    )
```

Comment: I couldn't get clearly from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027750/play-framework-form-only-18-params this answers. I need to submit more than `18` fields.

Comment: If I use less than `18` fileds I can submit my form.If I used more than `18`
fields using `nested values` I can't submit  form

Comment: You can't, as stated in the other answer. The only solution is to nest the values. A case class with 18 fields borders on the absurd.

Comment: I used the `nested values` as mentioned in my `questions's` `what I tried` heading